# Access android/ios/win device camera via cordova

Tags: android, ios, cordova, camera

I want to create Android/iOS/Windows app using cordova.
I have a problem to access the camera. I've used `getUserMedia` but in this way I cannot access the camera of my tablet. What is another way to access it? I have to use only a rear camera. Thanks a lot!

`getUserMedia` code:

```
 navigator.getUserMedia = navigator.getUserMedia ||navigator.webkitGetUserMedia
|| navigator.mozGetUserMedia || navigator.msGetUserMedia;

 var cam_video_id = "camsource"

window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
// Assign the <video> element to a variable
var video = document.getElementById(cam_video_id);
var options = {
    "audio": false,
    "video": true
};
// Replace the source of the video element with the stream from the camera
if (navigator.getUserMedia) {
    navigator.getUserMedia(options, function(stream) {
        video.src = (window.URL && window.URL.createObjectURL(stream)) || stream;
    }, function(error) {
        console.log(error)
    });
    // Below is the latest syntax. Using the old syntax for the time being for backwards compatibility.
    // navigator.getUserMedia({video: true}, successCallback, errorCallback);
} else {
    $("#qr-value").text('Sorry, native web camera streaming (getUserMedia) is not supported by this browser...')
    return;
}
}, false);
```

Comment: Use the cordova `media-capture` or `camera` plugins.

Answer (score 0):

You should obviously be using the [Camera plugin](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-camera/blob/master/doc/index.md) of Cordova. The documentation is available on link and you can set to use the rear camera by passing

```
cameraDirection: Camera.Direction.BACK
```

to options when opening camera like (from documentation)

```
navigator.camera.getPicture(onSuccess, onFail, {
  quality: 50,
  destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
  cameraDirection: Camera.Direction.FRONT
});

function onSuccess(imageURI) {
  var image = document.getElementById('myImage');
  image.src = imageURI;
}

function onFail(message) {
  alert('Failed because: ' + message);
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I need to use back camera and I don't have to capture image. I have to scan qr code. I couldn't find any example online.

Comment: @user3832184: Sorry, my bad about the camera direction, didn't pay enough attention. If you need to just get the QR data, you can use [Barcode scanner plugin](https://github.com/phonegap-build/BarcodeScanner).

Answer (score -1):

You may try ionic (based on cordova), it has qr reading functionalities